# How to prove this equation($x^n \frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n}=\cdots$)?

Tags: differential-operators

How to prove 
$x^n \frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n}=x\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\Big(x\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}-1\Big)\cdot\Big(x\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}-n+1\Big)$?
F. H. Jackson call this equation is Boole's equation, but when I Google "Boole's equation", I can't get any useful information!

Comment: What is that differential operator even acting on? This makes no sense as written.

Comment: @Kaynex This equation from F.H. Jackson, Mess. Math. 38, 57(1909), you can get it in this link(page.57): https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=jg5KAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA193&lpg=RA1-PA193&dq=the+messenger+of+mathematics+XXXVIII&source=bl&ots=-tcWhpwPb8&sig=2_7-J87jYX0rDMmkKKIU9gh8-X0&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBy_bVjJ7UAhWhhlQKHaVOA6cQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=the%20messenger%20of%20mathematics%20XXXVIII&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Use Leibnitz' rule for a higher derivative of a product:
$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(uv)=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom mk\frac{d^ku}{dx^k}\frac{d^{m-k}v}{dx^{m-k}}\ .$$
If $u=x$ this reduces to
$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(xv)=x\frac{d^mv}{dx^m}+m\frac{d^{m-1}v}{dx^{m-1}}\ .$$
Your result can now be proved by induction: assume the formula for $n-1$ and apply it to
$$x\frac{df}{dx}-(n-1)f\ .$$
Good luck!